# How to show <Image /> in React Native in a good way

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I'm using `react-native-camera` library. But I'm not sure if the problem is the library or the react native self. The problem occurs only on Android

I'm using `react native version 0.39` and the `android version is 6.1`.

The problem is when I try to take a few pictures in a row, after fifth taken image the app crashes. I'm not getting any errors of warnings.

It crashes also if the camera is opened and if I wait for about 15-20 seconds with camera opened, without taking photo.

On newer, better phone (s8 galaxy) and newer android versions (7) it works as expected, but on this one it isn't working. Thus, I suppose that it has something to do with **memory issues**. But I'm not sure.

I've added `largeMemoryHeap` to the manifest file.

In android studio I get log file as follows:

[image]

Thus, no errors, nothing. But the app doesn't work.

The stuck of code where those photos are rendered is as follows:

```
<ScrollView removeClippedSubviews={true}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content"/>
      <Zoom visible={this.state.zoomVisible} close={() => this.setState({zoomVisible: false})} image={this.state.zoomImage} imageIndex={this.state.zoomIndex} pictures={this.state.zoomPictures} remove={this.onRemoveImage.bind(this)} />
      <View style={{width: width, height: 1, backgroundColor: '#ddd'}} />
           <View style={styles.container}>
               {cards}
           </View>
 </ScrollView>
```

And one `card` is as follows, and I have a stuck of 10:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onPress} style={styles.card} underlayColor={s.color}>
       <View style={styles.innerCard}>
             <View style={styles.innerImageContainer}>
                  <Image contain='contain' style={styles.innerImage} source={this.props.image}/>
              </View>
              <View style={[styles.innerTitle, {borderBottomWidth: 4, borderBottomColor: this.props.mandatory ? this.props.noImage ? s.paletteMandatory : s.success : '#fff'}]}>
                   <Text style={styles.textTitle} allowFontScaling={false} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>{this.props.title}</Text>
              </View>
        </View>
</TouchableHighlight>);
```

I found somewhere that i need to add `removeClippedSubviews={true}` to scroll view, but it does not help.

On IOS it works just fine.

I would be infinitely grateful if someone has an idea?

Comment: I once had a somewhat similar problem working with `react-native-image-picker`. I did not really know what was happening but updating RN solved it.

Comment: Also, are you by any chance using `react-navigation`?

Comment: @Raymond I'm using `react-native-router-flux`. And it's a bit difficult to update RN, because I have dependencies whose only can work on 0.39 version.

Comment: Reason I asked about `react-navigation` is because of this https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/701#issuecomment-303833497